# How to add filter on object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, filter

I want to create a search box for my app but I'm not get any filter data from `array.filter()`

```
  getalldata = (e) => {
    let data = this.state.comData?.filter((resultFilterdata) => {
      if (resultFilterdata?.Name?.startsWith(e.target.value)) {
        return resultFilterdata;
      } else {
        return "err";
      }
    });
    console.log("-------------------", data);
  };
```

Comment: Presumably, you are returning a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value with `return resultFilterdata` in the block associated with the conditional expression (but that's not clear without a [mre]). Alternatively, you are returning `"err"` which is also truthy, so both cases would result in no items being filtered from the array. See the documentation for [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 1):

filter condition only accepts boolean value. Need to return a bool

```
  getalldata = (e) => {
    let data = this.state.comData?.filter((resultFilterdata) => {
      return resultFilterdata?.Name?.startsWith(e.target.value)
    });
    console.log("-------------------", data);
  };
```

Comment: "_Need to return a bool_": Technically, any value returned is coerced into a boolean, and in the code you've shown, an optional chaining short-circuit evaluation would result in `undefined` and be coerced into `false`.